# How to add routes in an SPA using Laravel?

Tags: laravel, single-page-application

I'm building an SPA. In my web.php file I have this:

```
Route::get('/{any}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Which is great, and I'm using Vue-Router for routing.
But I'm trying to add Stripe payments and in a lot of these videos that I've seen or articles that I've read, they often are still working with a few .blade files as well as .vue components.

I want to add a route for a blade file called checkout.blade.php
So now I will have this in web.php:

```
Route::get('/{any}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '.*');

Route::view('/checkout-now', 'checkout');
```

The issue is I don't see anything, just a blank white page when I go to this route, I assume it has to do with the first Route, but how do I get around this? How can I see .blade routes in my SPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I recommend to keep all your routes before the `any` route.

```
Route::view('/checkout-now', 'checkout');
.
.

Route::get('/{any}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '.*');    // Must be at the end
```

Comment: How can I get the User from a Route that is outside of my SPA?
I'm trying to get the User in a controller like this dd(Auth::user()); but it returns null because I'm using Laravel Passport for authentication for the SPA and I'm trying to get the User on a page "outside" of my SPA. Is it possible?

Comment: I am not too familiar with the passport functionality. I suggest checking the documentation or creating another question asking how to get auth()->user() in Laravel Passport.

Answer (score 0):

if you just need few route for vue router

```
$paths = ['vue-path', 'vue-path-id'];

foreach ($paths as $path) {
    Route::get($path, function () {
         return view('welcome');
    });
}

Route::view('/checkout-now', 'checkout');
```